# Managing duplicated data in WCF service

Tags: .net, wcf, datacontractserializer

I'm writing a WCF service that receives large messages from different clients.
Each of these messages consists of an object graph where many of the inner objects may be identical.
My service stores data from these messages into memory.

I'm trying to minimize the service's memory consumption. So I would like to store a single object instead of several identical objects that are received from the network (nested inside the object graph).

I'm using DataContractSerializer so first thing that comes in mind is using the [Object Graph Preservation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731073.aspx) option `preserveObjectReferences`, however there are some disadvantages to this approach:

- No interoperability with other technologies (if that was the only problem, I could live with that).
- Serialization and Deserialization process runs slower.
- Does not help much when objects are identical between different messages, possibly from different clients. Only good for objects on the same object graph in the same message.

So, next thing that comes to mind is using some kind of a cache.
When I get a message, I could traverse the object graph, use the cache to find a single instance for all identical objects, and update my storage with this single instance. When the storage disposes of all references to that object, it could be removed from the cache and free the memory for that object.

I could use [MemoryCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) but unfortunately my keys are not strings, and I don't want to convert them to strings only in order to store them in a cache. (What did Microsoft think to themselves when they limited the ObjectCache to string keys?)

So, before re-writing a Cache class with weak references and keys that can be compared with IEqualityComparer, I wanted to make sure I'm not missing anything here...

---

### My questions are:

- Is there a better approach to handling (and storing in memory) duplicated objects in a WCF service?
- Is there a good (efficient, general, open) cache implementation that I could use instead of re writing one?

Comment: do you know your using too much memory or are you optimizing prematurely?

Comment: @RalphWillgoss I know I'm using too much memory. Just looking at Process Explorer, I can see the memory consumption growing to hundreds of megabytes in a relatively short time.

Comment: How long do you need to keep these objects around for?

Comment: @RalphWillgoss pretty long. These objects describe a complex client state, and are updated by the clients. A client can (indirectly) add such objects and remove them from the service. I'm planning to add some expiration for these objects but it will be something between days and weeks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Microsoft App Fabric Server (Velocity) caching which fits in very nicely with the deployment of a WCF service.

[App Fabric Caching Features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh334364.aspx)

Comment: Looks like an overkill. And I don't see the benefit over MemoryCache (in my case I don't need distributed cache). The App Fabric Cache API is also based on string keys and not general comparable keys (as far as I can tell from docs) and I would like to avoid converting my keys to strings.